# Get Expression of property from collection element c#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Here is the problem:
I want to write extension method for getting property expression of collection field.

Here is an example.
I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Foo> Collection {get; set;}
}
```

And I have the following code:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = x => x.Collection.First().Id;
```

And I want to create an extension to get the same result expression with following signature:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id);

static Func<Foo, object> Field(this List<Foo> people, Expression<Func<Foo, object>> accessor)
{
    // implementation goes here
}
```

The main purpose of it is to generate path to property. In this case we need to get the following result: "Collection.Id". I already have method to convert Expression to property path. The `Field` method is an extension method, which I want. It should return the same result like `x => x.Collection.First().Id` but with the following signature: `x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id)`

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `x.Collection.Select(foo => foo.Id)`? Also you don't need the `Expression`, only the `Func`.

Comment: It is not very clear what do you want. What is `Field` method? How would you use this expressions? `Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id);` is an expression which is definitely a different expression compared to `Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = x => x.Collection.First().Id;`. Also is it planned to use this in some ORM like EF?

Comment: @GuruStron I need an Expression. The main purpose of it is to generate path to property. In this case we need to get the following result: "Collection.Id". I already have method to convert Expression to property path. The `Field` method is an extension method, which I want. It should return the same result like `x => x.Collection.First().Id` but with the following signature: `x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id)`.

Comment: There's no `List<T>.Field` property or method. *Why* do you need an expression? Why do you want the path to the first item's Id property? Are you trying to create an expression for Entity Framework? Or AutoMapper? You can't use a non-existent `Field` method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that there is no method `Field`. I want to create this extension method `Field` for `List` to get property expression and then from property expression get property string path. I'm not trying to create an expression for EF or Auto Mapper.

Comment: `x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id)` is not a signature. Why does the signature you show return `Func<Foo, object>`?

Comment: It isn't possible for the `Field` method inside an `Expression` lambda to modify the result of the compiler converting the lambda to an `Expression` tree - it will always be `x => x.Collection.Field(foo => foo.Id)` because `Field` is not executed when assigning the value to `expression`.

Answer (score 0):

Since no methods are executed when assigning a lambda to an `Expression` variable, it isn't possible to have a method as you describe work.

What you can do is create a method that takes in the collection expression and the property expression and creates a new `Expression` lambda that has the desired result.

```
Expression<Func<T, TProp>> Field<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>> collectionEFn, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> pathEFn) {
    // (Foo x)
    var parm = collectionEFn.Parameters[0];
    // x.Collection
    var collectionExpr = collectionEFn.Body;
    // y.Id
    var pathExpr = (MemberExpression)pathEFn.Body;
    // x.Collection.First()
    var firstExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "First", new[] { typeof(T) }, collectionExpr);
    // x.Collection.First().Id
    var newBody = Expression.Property(firstExpr, pathExpr.Member.Name);

    // (Foo x) => x.Collection.First().Id
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProp>>(newBody, parm);
}
```

With this method defined, you can call it as so:

```
var expr = Field((Foo x) => x.Collection, x => x.Id);
```

and the resulting value for `expr` will be an `Expression` tree representing `x => x.Collection.First().Id`

Note that the resulting type has the result type of the property referenced; if you want `object`, you would need to add a call to `Convert` to convert the `PropertyExpression` to the `object` type.

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on doing so (like the others I am not still clear about your goal of doing this), you can create a generic extension method that takes a lambda expression as a parameter, and returns an expression. Something like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, object>> Field<T, TPropert>(
            this IEnumerable<T> collection,
            Expression<Func<T, TPropert>> field)
        {
            var prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "x");
            var first = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "First", new[] { typeof(T) }, prm);
            var body = Expression.Property(first, ((MemberExpression)field.Body).Member.Name);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, field.Parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `first` is an `Expression` referencing `prm` but you create the final lambda with the parameter from `field` so you will get an error. Note also you never reference `collection` in your code...